# html span tag within span tag

Tags: jquery, html

Is it ok to have a span tag within another span tag? I need to format the digits within a span tag with jquery.

```
<span id="tprice">The price is: $95</span>
```

Comment: If you mean validity-wise, yes it's absolutely fine. Very common practice in fact

Comment: Can you give an example ot what you want because in your HTML code is see only 1 `<span>` ? I'm also interesting to know which formatting you will apply to price part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's OK. There's no rule which forbids, nor discourages this practice.

If that piece of HTML occurs more than once, replace `id="tprice"` by `class="tprice"`, because the ID must only occur once.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could even put a span tag within a span tag within a span tag ;).

This is actually pretty common and required in some instances such as when dealing with microformats/microdata.

Comment: Thanks, was wondering would it cause some issues with somes browsers